# How to sample equal number of units from each level of a variable in R?

Tags: r, sampling

Is there any function in R that will select equal number of units from every level of a variable? For example I have a data set consisting of a variable called "taste" and there are three levels of the variable taste say "bad", "normal" and "good". Now I want to select a sample which draws equal number of units from each level of the taste variable. How can I select such a sample in R?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it is easy for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with `rep` and `sample`

```
sample(rep(unique(data$taste), each = 25))
```

Comment: Where do you specify the name of the data and the variable name?